# Renaming categories

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, text-classification

```
    text       category
----------------------------------------------- 
    nike    shoes from nike brought by ankit
    flour   grocery
    rice    grocery
    adidas  shoes from adidas are cool
```

The above is my data-set format. How exactly do I generalize the category while categorising.
Example I want the output as:-

```
text       category
----------------------------------------------- 
    nike    shoes from brand
    flour   grocery
    rice    grocery
    adidas  shoes from brand
```

Comment: can you show us your attempt?

Comment: I haven't tried much, just read the CSV file using pandas. I had a lot of categories, to minimize my number of categories I want to Generalize them possibly without using regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use a custom function with `pd.DataFrame.apply`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['nike', 'flour', 'rice', 'adidas'],
                   'category': ['shoes from nike bought by ankit', 'grocery', 'grocery',
                                'shoes from adidas are cool']})

def converter(row):
    if row['text'] in row['category']:
        return row['category'].split(' from ')[0] + ' from brand'
    else:
        return row['category']

df['category'] = df.apply(converter, axis=1)

#            category    text
# 0  shoes from brand    nike
# 1           grocery   flour
# 2           grocery    rice
# 3  shoes from brand  adidas
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jpp. But,can this be done without using the TEXT column. Please check out the above edits.

Comment: @PoorneshV, I've rolled back your edit. Please make sure next time you ask the question correctly first. 24 people have potentially wasted their time looking at an incorrectly stated question. If this solves your stated problem, then feel free to accept. If you have a *different* problem, do some research, try to amend the code here. If you're stuck after a few hours, feel free to post stating exactly the line where you get stuck in your code.